Can someone please explain how xrandr --scale works?
From the docs:
              Changes the dimensions of the output picture.  If the y value is
              omitted,  the  x value will be used for both dimensions.  Values
              larger than 1 lead to a compressed screen (screen dimension big‐
              ger than the dimension of the output mode), and values less than
              1 lead to a zoom in on the output.  This option  is  actually  a
              shortcut version of the --transform option.

Let's try:
When I type --xrandr --output eDP 1.2x1.2 the screen gets smaller by about 20% (this checks out)
When I type --xrandr --output eDP 0.8x0.8 the screen gets absolutely massive, way more zoomed in than 20% (this falsifies the docs)
When I type --xrandr --output eDP 1x1 it gets even huger! It's zooming in. These transformations are being applied relatively it seems... but if this is the case then 1x1 should keep it totally static?
When I type --xrandr --output eDP 1.5x1.5 it gets smaller again. but it is still larger than --scale 1.2x1.2, further evidence of relative scaling.
When I type --xrandr --output eDP 1.5x1.5 nothing happens. Wait--does it mean that these transformations are not applied relatively?
When I type --xrandr --output eDP 2x2 it basically goes back to its native size... which is not at 2x scale! (the original size is 1920x1080 at a 1x scale).
So --scale is a shorthand of --transform, which is described as:
       --transform a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
              Specifies a transformation matrix to apply on the output.  A bi‐
              linear filter is selected automatically unless the --filter  pa‐
              rameter  is  also  specified.  The mathematical form corresponds
              to:
                     a b c
                     d e f
                     g h i
              The transformation is based on homogeneous coordinates. The  ma‐
              trix  multiplied by the coordinate vector of a pixel of the out‐
              put gives the transformed coordinate vector of a  pixel  in  the
              graphic  buffer.  More precisely, the vector (x y) of the output
              pixel is extended to 3 values (x y w), with 1 as the  w  coordi‐
              nate and multiplied against the matrix. The final device coordi‐
              nates of the pixel are then calculated with  the  so-called  ho‐
              mogenic  division  by  the  transformed  w coordinate.  In other
              words, the device coordinates (x' y') of the  transformed  pixel
              are:
                     x' = (ax + by + c) / w'   and
                     y' = (dx + ey + f) / w'   ,
                     with  w' = (gx + hy + i)  .
              Typically,  a  and  e  corresponds to the scaling on the X and Y
              axes, c and f corresponds to the translation on those axes,  and
              g,  h, and i are respectively 0, 0 and 1. The matrix can also be
              used to express more complex transformations  such  as  keystone
              correction,  or  rotation.   For  a rotation of an angle T, this
              formula can be used:
                     cos T  -sin T   0
                     sin T   cos T   0
                      0       0      1
              As a special argument, instead of passing a matrix, one can pass
              the  string  none,  in which case the default values are used (a
              unit matrix without filter).

So if I write `xrandr --output eDP --scale 1.5x1.5 this would be creating a transformation matrix as:
M = 
  1.5  0    0
  0    1.5  0
  0    0    1

where I am using * to denote the dot product, and (x,y) are some coordinates
So this would be equal to:
w' = (0x + 0y + 1) = 1
x' = (1.5x + 0y + 1) / w' = 1.5x
y' = (0x + 1.5y + 1) / w' = 1.5y

This entails a linear and relative transformation from the last x,y coordinates afaik! But wait, if according to the docs, scale values > 1 are supposed to compress the outputs, this seems like it is actually expanding the outputs since (x,y) is being multiplied by 1.5.
I'm using two monitors if this means anything, I'm not even getting into how it affects the other monitor screen space

I try to help you - yesterday i read the documentation and it was difficult to understand.i made this painting below. 
x'=x cos T + y -sin T + c  | a b c
y'=x sin T + y  cos T + f  | d e f   | g=0, h=0, i=1

x and y in pixels of the output mode on your monitor
x' and y' in pixels of the screen image in graphic buffer

I have one monitor:
e.g. angle 10 degrees, scale 1.2 -> cos 10 x 1.2 = 1.1818, sin 10 x 1.2 = 0.2084
xrandr --output "DVI-D-0" --transform 1.1818,-0.2084,0,0.2084,1.1818,0,0,0,1
output of calling xrandr after that xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2270 x 1677, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 2176x930+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

2176x930 must be image in graphic buffer
(2176 x cos 10 + 930 x sin 10) / 1.2 = 1920
but im not sure about the screen (yellow) in the painting!
Distance between the image in buffer top pixel to the monitor screen bottom would be:
2176 x sin 10 + 1080 x 1,2=1674
but thats including the blank monitor, but if the image is exceeding the monitor, i would bet the painting is right.
you can get back to old setting with:
xrandr --output "DVI-D-0" --transform 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
save every file you have open, two times i crashed my monitor had no signal, because of bad input and had to restart!
